# How do you create a mail merge from excel in microsoft word and then overlay multiple images on top of each other

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, mail-merge

I know how to insert images into mail merge in word one at a time and have them next to each other, but I want to mail marge three images each onto a printable label.

The first image is a background image (it will take up the entire label), the second image represents a group name, and the third image represents a number.

I want the first image as the background, the second and third images in the middle but at the top and bottom, evenly spaced, and the persons name to the left is number 4.

I know how to insert multiple images with mail merge but I don't know how to then change the positioning and layout of the images so they fall on top of or in front of each other.

**I can do this manually, but how do I get it to repeat the positioning and formatting of the images for each person in the mail merge.**

That's what I need help with, positioning the images over the top of each other automatically using the mail merge.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From memory you can use a lined INCLUDEPICTURE field for each image (use a dummy image during this process) and set them up how you want. Then press ALT+F9 to show field code and remove the path to the image and replace this with a MERGEFIELD. This field is where you would merge the path to the real image you want to use during mail merge.